# Why is the Microsoft.XNA framework missing?

Tags: xna, debian, monodevelop, monogame

I just apt-get installed monodevelop-monogame, tried to run the template right off the bat to make sure everything was fine and dandy. It failed to run, and when I tried to add missing references, I couldn't seem to find the XNA framework anywhere. Please help.

Comment: It's not a case issue, is it? Namespaces are case-sensitive, and the correct namespace is `Microsoft.Xna.Framework`.

Comment: It's a template so all the code is prewritten. It should compile right after installation. The problem is that the library is not there and I can't find anything on th internet that helps.

Comment: all of the Microsoft.Xna.* namespaces are located within the MonoGame.Framework reference

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there any reason why they don't make that distinction? Again I have not encountered any solution online, and the video I watched just showed installation and then running the program, so I assumed everything was packaged in.

Comment: Yeah i do wish they would package each namespace into it's own reference so that I could smoothly replace their terrible and flawed content pipelin